# sqlite setlocale error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a db in assets folder which is copied to the app. It is done exactly the same way as here: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

It all works fine in android 2.3.3 and above but doesn't work on the versions below. These are the phones I have tested the app on:

Samsung Galaxy S II - ANDROID 2.3.3 - working

Sony Ericsson neo -    ANDROID 2.3.3 - working

LG P350 - ANDROID 2.2.2 - error copying db

Sony Ericsson Xperia X8 - ANDROID 2.1-update 1 - error copying db

Samsung GalaxyACE Android 2.2.1. - error copying db

Samsung Galaxy    Tab 10.1 Android 3.1 - working

The error looks as follows:

```
10-13 13:03:43.773: ERROR/Database(2770): SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1950)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1818)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at org.com.db.DataBaseHelper.checkDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:81)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at org.com.db.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:42)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at org.com.SentencesActivity.onCreate(SentencesActivity.java:49)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-13 13:03:43.783: ERROR/Database(2770):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 13:03:43.793: VERBOSE/Debugger(2770): Copying db
10-13 13:03:43.893: WARN/dalvikvm(2770): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
```

Comment: make sure you have a android_metadata table in your database and locale set to default.

Comment: the only entry in android_metadata is en_US

Comment: actually you don't need to create this table in my case i only create my tables and when i pull the database from file explorer in eclipse it created this table automatically.so delete the table android_metadata and uninstall your app run the project again.if u want i can post the code.

Comment: I don't create it either. It is created automatically. It is working with Android 2.3.3 and above but it looks like the lower versions can't find the android_metadata table.

Comment: I thinkg the problem is because of the db being too big. It is around 18 mb. When I deleted some of the data and shrinked the db to 149 kb then it copied with no problems.

Comment: if that is the problem then i suggest to rename the db as "yourdatabase.mp3" hope this help.

Comment: Is there a max size for dbs in Android <2.3.3? Has the driver changed in 2.3.3? I don't know - just wanted to give you a hint for research.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error on nexus s android 2.3.6. DB size 384Kb. Even though the database does contain a value (en_GB) in android_metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't working on older versions of Android because the db was too big for them and the limit is 18mb. A solution to this is to split the db ino 18 files of 1 mb.